# Como saber se devo atualizar ou não um componente?

Tags: react, react-native, redux

Estou usando o `React`, `React Native` e `Redux` para fazer um aplicativo.

Tentei estudar um pouco sobre os ciclos de vida de um componente mas acabei ficando confuso em relação às diversas opções presentes na hora de iniciá-lo. O problema é o seguinte:

Quando um usuário estiver na screen `Feed` da minha aplicação, ele poderá encontrar um usuário e, eventualmente, tocar neste e isso abrirá a screen `Profile`. Nesta tela, no evento `componentDidMount()` eu faço uma busca usando o `Redux` para obter o objeto `user`. Acontece que, eu gostaria de mostrar uma tela de carregamento antes desse objeto chegar no `props` e estar "pronto". Eu consegui fazer isso. Se eu voltar para tela `Feed` e tocar para ver outro `user`, mesmo comportamento. O problema é que, se eu entrei na tela `Profile` para ver o usuário X, voltar para o Feed e tocar novamente no usuário X, a tela de carregamento será novamente mostrada, o que eu não quero por que, naturalmente, os dados já estão carregados.

Gostaria que a resposta contivesse a solução do problema e também uma análise se a forma e os eventos que estou usando estão corretos para esta ocasião.

```
class LocalInside extends Component {

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(this.props.user != null){
        if(prevProps.user == null){
            this.setState({showUser: true})
        }
        if(prevProps.user != null && prevProps.user != this.props.user){
            this.setState({showUser: true})
        }
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    if(this.props.userId != null){
        dispatch(getSingleUser(this.props.userId))
    }
}

state = {
    showUser: false
} 

render(){
    if(this.state.showUser){
        //Aqui mostra o user
    }else{
        //Aqui mostra o carregando.
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual middleware você usa (Redux Saga, Redux Thunk)? O Redux é um objeto, então dentro dele vai estar "salvo" o último dado carregado. Você pode checar se o id do usuário é o mesmo que está lá no objeto do Redux. Ai vc usa o middleware pra pegar isso e testar antes de chamar sua API.

Comment: Atualmente estou usando o Redux Thunk. Como poderia fazer essa verificação que tu mencionou?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa salvar na [store](https://redux.js.org/api/store) que os dados de perfil do usuário em questão já foram carregados. Isto é, no `componentDidMount`, você checa na store se o `hasUserDataLoaded` (Vinculado ao userId por exemplo) é `false` ou não. Se não tiver carregado, você renderiza a parte de carregamento *e* já dá um dispatch de uma [action](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) pra atualizar a store dizendo que `hasUserDataLoaded` agora é `true` (Esse dispatch é realizado dentro do `componendDidMount` mesmo). Desta forma, na próxima vez que o usuário acessar o perfil, ele não renderizará a parte de carregamento de novo. O ponto é, além de salvar os dados na store, precisa salvar o estado de carregamento (Ou checar de outra forma, checar se os dados estão vazios por exemplo).